# I have made a page in asp.net and c#, i want this page to open up as a popup window

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have made a page in asp.net and c#, i want this page to open up as a popup window.
what should i do with the code?
I am creating a student management system, when i click to add a student and the student already exists, i want a popup window to occur and ask whether you want to go back or you want to search the student using C# coding?

Comment: Need more information, what have you tried? What options are you considering? Post any code you have. Read [How To Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i have made a page which said that the enrollment number you entered already exists, you want to search that student or go back? 
i just want to know how to convert a simple page into a popup window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript's way:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function abrir(url, width, height)
        {
            window.open(url, '', width, height);
        }
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <a href="../yourpage.aspx"><img id="btnAyuda" onclick="abrir('../yourpage.aspx',750, 520);return false" /></a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey thanx EmmanuelRC for the help, but i'm a student learning asp.net using C#, i dont know java. so, can you tell me the code in C# so that i can understand better

Comment: As far as I know C# doesn't have a method to open a new window for web by itself, what it does is call lets say javascript's functions like: `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "UserPopup", "<script language='javascript'> alert('Hello World');</script>");` in your case to open that window, you could call another type of tool, but it all comes down to C# calling something else. But I totally recommend you to manage at least some basics of javascript/jquery to deal with this client side type of things and maybe a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

Use JavaScript's window `function`:

```
var popup = window.open('url');
```

Or the confirm `function`:

```
function showConfirm()
{
  var r=confirm("Do you want to go back or you want to search the student?")
  if (r==true)
  {
     alert("You pressed OK!")
  }
  else
  {
   alert("You pressed Cancel!")
  }
}
```

Comment: thanx Yair, will only be able to check the code on monday as i dont have Microsoft visual studio installed on my pc, thanx for help anyways

Comment: i used the above coding, i received an error: 
the name window does not exists in the current context.

Comment: @AlokWadhwa I don't know how you code it but take a look at this nice explanations and examples article of the `window.open` function: [Using the window.open method](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)